# BackgroundWorker reporting activity progress

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working on a WinForm project, using `BackgroundWorker`, for a data extraction procedure, and I periodically have to update a progressbar that shows the activity progress.

My question is: is there a way to decouple the extraction logic (in my case implemented in different classes) from the "progress report" logic?

Comment: If you are *outside* the logic that does the work, how do you know how much progress it has made?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that's clear. so, if I want to implement my extraction logic in another class I suppose I have to find a way to recall the `ReportProgress(percentProgress);` from my "extraction class"... Am I wrong?

Comment: Not necessarily: your working logic has to decide when the progress changes, but it does not need to call `ReportProgress` directly: your background worker could insert its own delegate between the working logic's reporting of the progress and the call to `ReportProgress`; see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot decouple the logic of reporting the progress from the logic that does the work, but you can decouple the logic that reports progress from the logic that updates the progress bar.

One way of doing it is by providing an event in the class that does the work to report its progress to interested parties that registered an event handler with the logic that does the work, and call it periodically as the progress changes.

Your background worker would then become an "interested party" by registering to receive these event notifications from the "do the work" logic, and call its own `ReportProgress` with the data that it receives from the event. This way the "do the work" logic could remain unaware of the `ReportProgress` of the background worker.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. I'm not so experienced on WinForms yet, so I was looking for a confirm. Thank you very much.